# Force a line break in Words. Woocommerce Cart Page (Product Describe)

Tags: css, woocommerce, text, cart, line-breaks

I want to set force a line break in some words.

It looks like that now:

Langgymnasium, schulbegleitend, 09:00 -
11:15, 03.09, 10.09, 17.09, 24, 09, 01.10, 29.10, 05.11, 12.11, 19.11, 26.11, 03.12, 10.12, 17.12, 14.01, 21.01, 28.01, 04.02
× 18

And i want it like that:

**Langgymnasium, schulbegleitend**

**09:00 - 11:15**

**03.09, 10.09, 17.09, 24, 09, 01.10, 29.10, 05.11, 12.11, 19.11, 26.11, 03.12, 10.12, 17.12, 14.01, 21.01, 28.01, 04.02**

How can I resolve that ?

Thank You very much!

[image: Woocommerce page]

Answer (score 0):

So first, based off the screen shot and the arrows you have pointing, a `<table>` element will behave differently than most other HTML elements.

So you most likely will have to wrap the inner text of `.product-name` with some other HTML element like `<div>` or `<span>` maybe, and then use the CSS you have with `word-break`.

A side from that, you can potentially try changing the `table-layout` property in the CSS:

#### Solution with the CSS word-wrap property

Use the `border-collapse` property set to `collapse` and `table-layout` property set to `fixed` on the `<table>` element. Also, specify the `width` of the `<table>`. Then, set the `word-wrap` property to its `break-word` value for `<td>` elements and add `border` and `width` to them.

Source: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-wrap-the-content-of-a-table-cell.html